# Two different scaling methods comparison Normalizer and Standardizer

Tags: python, scaling

I have defined two classes of scaling methods. The top one works, however, the bottom doesn't work, I'm kinda confused. Is it better not to use the methods that are defined below in the init step?

```
class Normalizer():
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.params = []
        for col in dataframe.columns:
            self.params.append(x_min_max(dataframe[col]))
            
    def x_min_max(self,data):
        minimum = min(data)
        maximum = max(data)
        return minimum, maximum

    def normalize_data(self, x):
        normalized = []
        for i,val in enumerate(x):
            x_max = self.params[i][0]
            x_min = self.params[i][1]
            normalized.append((x[i]-x_min)/(x_max-x_min))
        return normalized
```

```
class Standardizer():
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.params = []
        for col in dataframe.columns:
            self.params.append(x_avg_std(dataframe[col]))
            
    def x_avg_std(data):
        avg = sum(data) / len(data)
        std = (sum([((x - avg) ** 2) for x in data]) / (len(data) - 1)) ** 0.5
        return avg, std

    def standardize_data(self, x):
        standardized = []
        for i,val in enumerate(x):
            x_avg = self.params[i][0]
            x_std = self.params[i][1]
            standardized.append((x[i] - x_avg)/x_std)
        return standardized
```

"Normalizer" will do the scaling job without reporting an error. However,
"Standardizer" to the same data frame, "NameError: name 'x_avg_std' is not defined" shows up

Comment: Can you spell out more precisely what you mean by "the bottom doesn't work"?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get a runtime error, unexpected result, syntax error?

Comment: sure, when I apply the "Standardizer" to the same dataframe, and error "NameError: name 'x_avg_std' is not defined" shows up, however, the Normalizer will do the scaling job without reporting error.

Comment: Have you noticed in the definition of `x_avg_std` in `Standardizer` there is no call to `self`?